# how do i link paypal account with online store using php

Tags: php, paypal

I am not sure what this is called but here is what i am looking to do.

I am trying to make a php script that will create a link between our store account and paypal buyer, so that when they click our buy button it will process the payment without any future confirmations or user actions.

I have tried the paypal sdks and integration wizard no luck, Does anyone know of a working example of what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Billing agreement(also called Reference Transactions) allows customer to agree the payment once on your website or app, then you call an API with the billing agreement ID to tell PayPal to charge the customer. Please see document [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/#id094TB0Y0J5Z__id094TB4003HS) . You will need to contact PayPal to enable you to use Billing agreement, it's not easy to get approval:(

Answer (score 0):

Integrating Paypal buttons are pretty straightforward.

Go to your merchant account.

Go to your Create Paypal Button page.

Choose whatever the button types you want. Configure it with Price etc.

Now just copy and paste the code generated.

It just works.

P.S
There is an option in your merchant account page to set the returning address from Paypal. You can set a returning page and catch all the transaction details via HTTP Post method when it is called by Paypal.

There is this Sandbox account type in Paypal which you can do a lot of playing with.

Comment: we are not using buttons, we have a client program that talks to a server in this case its php. we need the php script to tell paypal to charge the user. an example would be how game company store paypal account to charge the users. secondlife does this but haw can i?

Comment: You have to use Reference Transactions API in this case.